# Is there any way to preprocess data read with tensorflow_io.IODataset.from_hdf5

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I try to construct a machine learning model in python using Tensorflow. The problem is that the training data don't fit in the memory. They are saved as a large HDF5 file. The input is a 4D array that stores a stack of images (each image has more than 10 channels, e.g. infrared channel). I managed to read the data using the code from this post:
[Tensorflow-IO Dataset input pipeline with very large HDF5 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097970/tensorflow-io-dataset-input-pipeline-with-very-large-hdf5-files)

```
import tensorflow_io as tfio
BATCH_SIZE = 256
EPOCHS = 50

# Create an IODataset from a hdf5 file's dataset object  
x_train = tfio.IODataset.from_hdf5(training_name, dataset='/X')
y_train = tfio.IODataset.from_hdf5(training_name, dataset='/Y')

# Zip together samples and corresponding labels
train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_train,y_train,)).batch(
    BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Can I preprocess the data before they are fed into the training? I want to normalise the input with respect to a global mean and std along each channel. Moreover, the target output, Y, is a float array representing probabilities and I would like to round it to a binary format for a classification task.

Answer (score 1):

For normalization, you can use [this code snippet](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#normalizing_numerical_features). It uses a Normalization layer which is one of the core preprocessing layers.
You can use the `axis` argument to specify which elements/axis to normalize. You can also use this layer inside your model.

For converting target output Y to binary, `tf.math.round` might be useful along with `tf.data.Dataset.map`. Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map)